# Is there a way to access nested DOM Elements in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

In my app, I have an input field and a ref that stores the value of the user input. I also have a bunch of React Links in a div that serve as recommended keywords for the user to search.

Is there a way for me to dynamically modify the React Link element that has the same text as the user input?

EG: user inputs "shoe" and there's a  `<Link to="/display?shoe"> Shoe </Link>`, then I can get that element and add some inline css to it.

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mRtk.png)

Answer (score 0):

In React you can access the DOM element using Refs.

Creating Refs:
create using React.createRef() and attach it to the  React elements using ref attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Would I have to create a ref for every single Link element? Or is there a way to create a ref for the div the holds all the links, and access items within that div though the ref.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you store the user input in state. So whenever state changes the `Link` is updated

Example:

```
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState(''); // store input value
<Link to=`/display?${userInput}`>{userInput}</Link>
```